# how to install octave packages on google colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, octave

I need to run some matlab code on google colab that needs 'image' package. I tried
`pkg install -forge image`
but that through an error. please help!

Answer (score 0):

For me, I need to install "image" package.

My solution is,
run the following command in colab：

```
!apt-get install -y liboctave-dev
```

Then create a new matlab file "install.m" with code:

```
pkg install -forge image
```

then run the following command in colab：

```
!octave -W yourPath/install.m
```

which you only need to run once.

After this, when you need to run the .m file that requires the "image" package, add:

```
pkg load image
```

to the beginning of the code.